# Iterate Through a Struct?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to be able to iterate through the values of a struct in C# (.Net 2.0).  This is to be done at runtime, with no knowledge of the possible values in the struct.

I was thinking along the lines of either using Reflection to add the struct values to a list, or converting the struct to a data structure that implements the IEnumerable interface.  Can anyone provide any pointers?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Andy.

Comment: Are you sure you'r not really meaning enum instead of struct?. The question will have some sense in this case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What exactly do you mean - the various fields within a struct? Or properties perhaps? If so, `Type.GetFields()` or `Type.GetProperties()` is the way to go.

Are you absolutely sure you need to use a struct, by the way? That's rarely the best design decision in C#, particularly if the struct contains multiple values.

EDIT: Yes, it seems that structs are being used for legacy reasons.

One thing I didn't mention before: if the struct's fields aren't public, you'll need to specify appropriate BindingFlags (e.g. `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic`).

Comment: Jon,

I would prefer to avoid them myself,  but I'm dealing with a legacy application.  Thanks for you advice.

Comment: Jon, Thanks again. I was able to iterate using the following code:
Type structType = typeof(MyStruct);
FieldInfo[] fields = structType.GetFields();
Foreach(FieldInfo field in fields) { ... }

Answer (score 2):

At the simplest level, assuming that you want to iterate over the properties:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = myStructInstance.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties) {
    Console.WriteLine(property.GetValue(myStructInstance, null).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use something like the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MY_STRUCT
{
   public uint aa;
   public uint ab;
   public uint ac;
}

MY_STRUCT pMS = new MY_STRUCT();

FieldInfo[] fields = pMS.GetType().GetFields();
foreach (var xInfo in fields)
   Console.WriteLine(xInfo.GetValue(pMS).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on every struct, you have to use reflection. If you want to declare a set of structs with this ability, you can make them implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` and define `GetEnumerator()` as:

```
yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Field1", Field1);
yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Field2", Field2);
// ... and so forth
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [`system.reflection.propertyinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) document for an example of using Reflection.