# Iterating through Struct members

Tags: c#

Lets say we have a struct

```
Struct myStruct
{
   int var1;
   int var2;
   string var3;
   .
   .
}
```

Is it possible to to iterate through the structure's members by maybe using foreach? I have read some things on reflection, but I am not sure how to apply that here.

> There are about 20 variables in the struct. I am trying to read values
>   off a file and trying to assign them to the variables but don't want
>   to call file.ReadLine() 20 times. I am trying to access the member
>   variables through a loop

Comment: @kr13: You almost *certainly* shouldn't have a struct with 20 fields in it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: Turn your struct into an array or List, and/or use a Serialization library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate Through a Struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661834/iterate-through-a-struct)

Comment: @JonSkeet: The 16 byte size limit is a very weak one and is frequently ignored when dealing with unmamaged APIs or DTOs. But the OP probably shouldn't use a struct for lots of other reasons.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, I don't mind the size limit so much, but this almost certainly doesn't "logically represent a single value, similar to primitive types".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You apply reflection in pretty much the same way as normal, using [`Type.GetFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx):

```
MyStruct structValue = new MyStruct(...);

foreach (var field in typeof(MyStruct).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                 BindingFlags.Public))
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(structValue));
}
```

Note that if the struct exposes properties (as it almost certainly should) you could use `Type.GetProperties` to get at those.

(As noted in comments, this may well not be a good thing to do in the first place, and *in general* I'm suspicious of user-defined structs, but I thought I'd include the actual answer anyway...)

EDIT: Now it seems you're interested in *setting* the fields, that's slightly more complicated due to the way value types work (and yes, this really *shouldn't* be a struct.) You'll want to box *once*, set values on the single boxed instance, and then unbox at the end:

```
object boxed = new MyStruct();

// Call FieldInfo.SetValue(boxed, newValue) etc

MyStruct unboxed = (MyStruct) boxed;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it seems like I might be making things unnecessarily complicated. I will see if I can achive the same thing using lists.

Comment: "Note that if the struct exposes properties (as it almost certainly should) you could use Type.GetProperties to get at those."? May I ask why a struct should expose properties? Why not simple variables?

Comment: @Naresh: Because fields should be a storage concern, rather than part of the public API - at least in almost all cases. (There are exceptions.) See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Comment: thank you very much @JonSkeet .. i got your new book delivered too.. i will go in the book for more details..