# How do I access elements in a packed struct by index?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct packed {
    type1_t  info1;
    type2_t  info2;
} module_info_registers_t;

typedef struct packed {
    logic  [0:0] data1;
    logic  [2:0] data2;
    logic [11:0] data3;  
    logic [15:0] data4;  
} info1;

typedef struct packed {
    logic  [1:0] data1;
    logic  [3:0] data2;
    logic [10:0] data3;  
    logic [14:0] data4;  
} info2;
```

As you can see, type1_t and type2_t are defined as 32-bit data structures.

I want to instantiate the following:

```
module_info_registers_t myregs;
```

and I want to access the registers based on index (rather than having to type myreqs.info2.data4):

```
myregs[1].data4
```

This is because the definition of module_info_registers_t will change from time to time and is autogenerated, so I don't want to hardcode 'info2' in my RTL

However, I am getting an error saying that I can't have a slice on a scalar object.

I understand that for some reason I can't access the data in the way I want to. Is there another way I can do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613782/iterating-through-struct-members  I would iterate through all the members into a list then you can access by index.

Comment: @EJD, this is for verilog. Does you answer still apply? Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about verilog it was more to point you into a direction.

Comment: If the name (`info2`) will change, wont the index (`[1]`) change for that particular register as well? Ideally, you just have names for your registers that dont change and you can always refer to the register as `info2`

Comment: @Unn, yes, the data will change. I have an FSM that is sending the data from some registers to another module. It does this for all the registers, but the total number of registers is unknown when writing the RTL, but an upper bound is known so that the index bit-width is set appropriately. The code needs to be flexible for a large number of 32-bit data structures in that struct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in verilog to do what you want. You might get around using macros, or bit-level access to the struct fields.

Macros can be done like this:

```
`define ACCESS_REG(R, NUM) R.info``NUM
module_info_registers_t regs;
`ACCESS_REG(regs, 1).data1 = 0;
```

The above will work, assuming certain naming conventions applied to the fields.

with bit-level access you need to be able to calculate offset and width of every struct member, making declaration and usage more complicated. Here is a very simplified System Verilog example for clarity:

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic [1:0] f1;
  logic [2:0] f2;
  logic [3:0] f3;
} sp_t;

sp_t sp;
sp[$bits(sp.f3) + $bits(sp.f2)  +: $bits(sp.f3)] = 2'b10;
```

The above example will set 'sp.f1'.

So, in your case you can create arrays of parameters describing offset and widths of the corresponding fields and use them for indexing. So, something like that might work in your case:

```
parameter int info[2] = {0, 32};
parameter int data1Offset[2] = {31, 30};
parameter int data1Width[2] = {1, 2};

module_info_registers_t regs;
regs[info[1] + data1Offset[1] +: data1Width[1]] = 0;
```