# iterator nested struct in c#

Tags: c#, struct

Lets say we have a struct

```
public struct a{
  public struct b;
  public struct c;
   .
   .
   .
  public struct n;
}

public struct b{
 public int b1 = 1;
 public int b2 = 2;
}
```

I want to print all member of struct such as

struct a

struct b

b1=1
b2=2

.

.

.

struct n

member

[I already reference this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613782/iterating-through-struct-members)

but it use field , I don't know how to access nested struct by field .

Comment: That's no valid C#. "`public struct b;`" is invalid.

Comment: FYI your `struct b` is already 8 bytes and your `struct a` seems to have many other `struct`. `struct` should not surpass 16 bytes and according your code i see you might hit 8-9 times the limit of what a `struct` should be. `a` should be a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the syntax errors in your code, for listing the public members of `a` you would use `typeof(a).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public)` and for listing the fields of `b` it would be `typeof(b).GetFields()`.

```
var aType = typeof(a);
foreach(var member in aType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public))
    Console.WriteLine(member.Name);

var bType = typeof(b);
foreach(var field in bType.GetFields())
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BBG6wa

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented recursively:

```
    void PrintMembers(Type type, object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(type.Name);

        foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                         BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                         BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            object value = field.GetValue(o);
            if (field.FieldType.IsPrimitive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", field.Name, value);
            }
            else
            {
                PrintMembers(value.GetType(), value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call it like

```
 var myStruct = new a();

 PrintMembers(typeof(a), myStruct);
```

Keep in mind this call requires boxing of `myStruct` object.